# How to map a specific Google Fusion Table Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

The "new" look for Google Fusion Tables allows you to create multiple "map" tabs (and others like "charts" and "summary").  My question is: how do you use Google Maps API to call a specific map tab you have created?  For example, you may have a map tab you have designed with the following URL:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1InbiFbInR8OGcMgOngf3j2Bb2FTpEkZQuT1hNMo#map:id=4

The fusion table id is 1InbiFbInR8OGcMgOngf3j2Bb2FTpEkZQuT1hNMo, and the map:id = 4.  So in Google Maps API, you can layer this table as:

```
crime = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Address',
        from: '1InbiFbInR8OGcMgOngf3j2Bb2FTpEkZQuT1hNMo'
    },
});
crime.setMap(map);
```

But this will not apply any of the stylings or infowindows you may have done on your map tab.  How do I tell Google Maps API to grab a specific map tab?

FYI, switching to "classic" view let's me apply a single map style to the fusion table that DOES get applied by the code above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the `styleId` and `templateId` of the view.
Click the particular tab->publish->get HTML and Javascript and you will get what you need.