# polyline, customize color style fusion table

Tags: google-maps-api-3, styles, google-fusion-tables, polyline

I've create a fusion table, with polylines, I diplay this on a map. with :

```
var filter = [];
 var j = document.getElementsByName('sousmenu4');
 for (var i = 0, k; k = j[i]; i++) {
   if (k.checked) {
     filter.push('\'' + k.value + '\'');
   }
 }

 if (filter.length) {
  if (!layer3.getMap()) {
    layer3.setMap(map);
  }
   layer3.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: '1twRoA12Qc7toIRQe_Uk6XKFS8Ts-V_AvcHZahGlx',
      where: '\'indice\' IN (' + filter.join(',') + ')',

    },


   });

} 
 else {
   layer3.setMap(null);
}
}
```

so far, so good,

Now, I have add a column in my fusion table, and I insert a color code for each row/polyline.

It's possible to display the color style on map ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [FusionTables User Interface](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2681556), see "Use the "Column" option to assign a precise color to each row of data in the table." under "Specify a color for each polygon" (works for polylines also).

from that post:

**2. Change polygon colors**

> These steps describe how to customize the fill color for polygons. The same options apply to polygon border color, border width, and lines.
>
> There are several customization options, each described in more detail below:

- One color for all features ("Fixed")
- Apply color based on the data ("Buckets" or "Gradient")
- **Specify exact color of each feature ("Column")**

**Specify a color for each polygon**

> Use the "Column" option to assign a precise color to each row of data in the table. This option gives you the most control over the appearance of each feature on your map. In order to specify a color based on "Column", the table you're using needs to have a column with a color entered for each row.
>
> Color can be specified two different ways you may be familiar with from the web: css color names or RGB hex notation. Case doesn't matter. For hex color codes, a leading # is optional. Add two optional characters at the end of the hex color to specify opacity. For example: 00 is transparent; 80 is 50% opaque; FF is completely opaque.

```
"Value" "Effect"
blue    blue
#0000FF blue
#0000FFFF   opaque blue
#0000FF80   50% opaque blue
#0000FF00   completely transparent blue
```

> If the table you're using doesn't already have a column of hex color codes, you can either add a column of color specs or you can merge your table with a table that has a column of color specs.

To get those styles to appear on your Google Maps Javascript API v3 map, follow the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094213/how-to-map-a-specific-google-fusion-table-map/16094425#16094425) to find and apply the correct styleId and templateId for that particular map in the UI. (Click the particular tab->publish->"get HTML and Javascript")

Comment: Yes, but this works fine with user interface, but when I try with API, he doesn't display colors...

Comment: You need to use the templateId and styleId for the map displayed in the User Interface.  There is an option to export javascript/html which will have those values in it.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094213/how-to-map-a-specific-google-fusion-table-map/16094425#16094425)